# Optimizing Division by Unknown Denominator Without Using Division Operator

Tags: integer-division

I am trying to write a C function that performs the following calculation at runtime:

Numerator/Denominator

where:

Numerator is a prior calculation result, is always positive, and is greater than the Denominator

and,

Denominator is such that (1 <= Denominator <= 64).

The runtime calculation must be fast, i.e. fewest cycles, so the division operator is out of the question. I have looked at recursive subtraction and bitwise long division, but I am trying to find another solution.

Any Help?

Comment: Where is the code you hahve trid?

Comment: How much greater is Numerator - i.e. is the expected quotient capped at some value? Perhaps a binary search using multiplication (which still isn't extremely fast, but is faster than division) - try `10 * Denominator`, if that's too small try `100 * Denominator`, if that's too big, try `55 * Denominator`, etc... It will take O(log2(Quotient)) steps...

Comment: The numerator is 48,000,000 to 768,000,000

Comment: What kind of CPU are we talking about here?  If it has a clz instruction, things can get faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea, which uses one multiplication and one shift, so it'll be faster than a division on most systems. Since your numerators top out at 768,000,000 ~= 30 bits, we don't have much room left in a 32-bit word, so we'll have to use 64-bit multiplication.

The main idea is to take advantage of the fact that:

```
x / y == (x * k) / (y * k)
```

and that dividing by a power of 2 is a simple, fast bit shift.

So to pick a particular example, assume `x = 700,000,000` and `y = 47` (so the correct quotient is 14,893,617). To avoid rounding errors, our shift needs to be approximately the size of our largest possible numerator - 30 bits. Find the value of `k` that gives the closest approximation to `y * k = 2^30`, which is `k = 22845571` in this case. Then `x * k = 0x38D08C4CE6F500`. Shifting this by 30 bits gives `0xE34231 = 14,893,617`, our expected quotient. It's possible you may need to add 1-2 more bits for some combinations of numerator/denominator for rounding purposes, unless being off by 1 in your quotient is acceptable.

The exercise then becomes creating a lookup table with the right multipliers for each of the possible denominators.

EDIT: as pointed out in a comment below, choosing `k = (2^30 + y - 1) / y` should give better and more consistent results than simply `k = round(2^30 / y)`.

Comment: Since shifting always truncates the result and truncating always generates a negative error, you should always round the multiplier *up* so the errors cancel. I.e. `k = (2^30 + y-1) / y`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Hmm.... good point. And probably a better way to improve accuracy than just adding another bit or two.

Comment: Awesome.  My problem has been solved.  The Table lookup for k values did it nicely.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Big @ss table would work for small numbers:

```
unsigned int divTable[kMaxNumerator][64] = {...}
```

Where you put the values of each possible divide in there.  Not very practical above a certain sizes, but it does work for contained cases and was a common solution for texture mapping way back in the day :)  Then I read your comments and see that you are in the 768,000,000 range and this because completely impractical unless you can handle quite a bit of precision loss.